# File Comparer doesn't write result to file

Tags: java

Hiho guys,
I am writing an easy application, which should open two .txt files, take first line of the first file and then iterate through every line of second file. If it finds the same String in second file, then it should write this string to outputfile.txt with nextline. After the loop over the second file is done, it should take the second line from the first line and search for the same String and if finds then writes it with nextline.
I've tried it by myself but it does nothing, I mean it doesn't put any text into outputfile.txt, even if I am sure that there are same words.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String sourceFileName = "C:\\Users\\Maciej\\IdeaProjects\\spring5webapp\\FileTextChecker\\src\\com\\company\\BootfileRO.txt";
    String comparingFileName = "C:\\Users\\Maciej\\IdeaProjects\\spring5webapp\\FileTextChecker\\src\\com\\company\\BootfileSK.txt";
    String outputFileName = "C:\\Users\\Maciej\\IdeaProjects\\spring5webapp\\FileTextChecker\\src\\com\\company\\output.txt";

    System.out.println("Starting ...  ");



    File file1 = new File(sourceFileName);
    File file2 = new File(comparingFileName);
    PrintWriter file3 = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    String line1 = "";
    String line2 = "";

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(file1);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file2);
    while(scan1.hasNextLine()){
        line1 = scan1.nextLine();
        while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
            line2 = scan2.nextLine();
            if(line1.equals(line2)){
                file3.println(line1);
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }


    }
    file3.close();





   // Comparer comparer = new Comparer(sourceFileName, comparingFileName, oFN);
   // comparer.compare();


   // CompareByScanner compareBYScanner = new CompareByScanner(sourceFileName, comparingFileName, outputFileName);
   // compareBYScanner.compare();


    }


}
```

To be honest, it looks like the "equals" function can't find the same strings, but I am sure they exists.

Comment: Hints: A) start with known *small* files B) add trace prints to show you *what exactly* your code is doing. And unrelated: you are only closing 1 out of 3 file objects.

Comment: So, I've added two test files:
A:
aaa
bbb
ccc

B:
bbb
zxc
qfd

It prints bbb to output but I have no idea why it stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that scan2 never resets, therefore after comparing the first line of file1, scan2.hasNextLine() will return false and therefore does not compare any further lines. Instead, set scan2 equal to a new Scanner at every iteration of the scan1 loop. This will set it to the start of the file. Then, after scanning the file, close the Scanner. New code:

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String sourceFileName = "src/output/compare1.txt";
String comparingFileName = "src/output/compare2.txt";
String outputFileName = "src/output/output.txt";

System.out.println("Starting ...  ");



File file1 = new File(sourceFileName);
File file2 = new File(comparingFileName);
PrintWriter file3 = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

String line1 = "";
String line2 = "";

Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(file1);
Scanner scan2;
while(scan1.hasNextLine()){
    line1 = scan1.nextLine();
    scan2 = new Scanner(file2);
    while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
        line2 = scan2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Line 1: " + line1 + "\n" + "Line 2: " + line2);
        if(line1.equals(line2)){
            file3.println(line1);
        }
    }
    scan2.close();
}
file3.close();





// Comparer comparer = new Comparer(sourceFileName, comparingFileName, oFN);
// comparer.compare();


// CompareByScanner compareBYScanner = new CompareByScanner(sourceFileName, 
comparingFileName, outputFileName);
// compareBYScanner.compare();


}


}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've found a mistake in a file and found the solution by myself... however I really appreciate your help!